# is it possible to convert prestashop website into a normal cms website?

Tags: content-management-system, prestashop

I need to use a prestashop website as a CMS website so that I can hide all the pricing features, Add to cart features..I want to manage my prestashop website as a portfolio for my business. Since I can't afford to sell my products online right now and at a later stage I could activate the features like add to cart and pricing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Preferences -> Products - Catalog mode -> On*

It will disable all "shop features"